# sending a message through a discord bot when a condition is met

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to send automated discord message through the bot when a does not equal b. I have other commands working but they all require user input through discord

```
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import time
import threading

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
TOKEN = ('my bot token')


def rep():
  threading.Timer(10.0, rep).start()
rep.a = ("aaa")
rep.b = ("bbb")
if rep.a == rep.b :
    print("a does in fact equal b")
    #other stuff

else:
    print("a does not equal b")
    #send a message through the discord bot
    #other stuff
rep()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I cannot understand what you want. See this example before making a project: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discord.py actually has loops built in

I think this should help:

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    your_loop_name.start()

a = "aaa"
b = "bbb"


@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def your_loop_name():
    global a, b
    print(a)
    print(b)
    if a != b:
        # You can put everything here, this is just an example
        user = client.get_user(PUT_YOUR_USER_ID_HERE)
        await user.send('a is not equal to b')
    else:
        pass

# ----------------

@client.command()
async def change(ctx, a_b="-", *, value=None):
    global a, b
    if a_b == "a":
        if not value:
            return
        a = value
    elif a_b == "b":
        if not value:
            return
        b = value
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Please enter a or b")
```

The loop executes every 10 seconds, and checks if a is not equal b ( != )

If you execute the command 
"change b aaa"
The Bot will stop sending you that it is not equal and will print "aaa" 2x!

I hope I could help,
If you have questions, write me on discord: V Enc OnPoint.#2641